# How to insert a image in WordPress that will display on admin product image?

Tags: wordpress

> $insert = $wpdb->insert( $prefix."posts", array("post_title" => $posTitle,"post_content" => $postContent,"post_status" => "publish","post_type" =>"product"));

I insert image path in wordpress posts table and post parent contain ID of product ID also add _thumbnail_id in postmeta table product id
my main focus is to display image in post product page in wp-admin

Answer (score 0):

Image will be inserted in the `postmeta` table with the id of related post. If you are using the default post of WordPress you can get image by using the function `get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $size, $attr );` or you can fetch these from `postmeta`.

Comment: see I have woo commerce plugin for product and insert image path in posts table under ID of product where I use product ID in the image  post_parent and also in postmeta metakey _thumbnail_id of product ID

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $size, $attr ); for the custom post type too.
See the link
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail